# How to return back to script directory after changing the directory from within the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am changing the directory inside a function, but am not able to get back to the directory where the script resides.

I tried using `__FILE__` and `sys.argv[0]` for getting the name of the file and the directory accordingly but that didn't help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import sys, os

script = sys.argv[0]
script_path = os.path.dirname(script)

def fun1():

    abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    print('abspath = {}'.format(abspath))
    print('file = {}'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    print('__file__ = {}'.format(__file__))
    dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
    print('dname = {}'.format(dname))
    os.chdir(dname)
    print('CWD - fun1() = {}'.format(os.getcwd()))

def fun2():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    if cwd != '/xyz/testdir':
        os.chdir("/xyz/testdir")
    print('CWD - fun2() = {}'.format(os.getcwd()))

def main():

    while True:
        print('Entering fun1()')
        fun1()
        print('Entering fun2()')
        fun2()
        print('Sleeping for 5 secs')
        time.sleep(5)
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Actual result -

```
Entering fun1()
abspath = /abc/chdir.py
file = chdir.py
__file__ = chdir.py
dname = /abc
CWD - fun1() = /abc
Entering fun2()
CWD - fun2() = /xyz/testdir
Sleeping for 5 secs

Entering fun1()
abspath = /xyz/testdir/chdir.py
file = chdir.py
__file__ = chdir.py
dname = /xyz/testdir
CWD - fun1() = /xyz/testdir
Entering fun2()
CWD - fun2() = /xyz/testdir
Sleeping for 5 secs
```

Expected result -

```
Entering fun1()
abspath = /abc/chdir.py
file = chdir.py
__file__ = chdir.py
dname = /abc
CWD - fun1() = /abc
Entering fun2()
CWD - fun2() = /xyz/testdir
Sleeping for 5 secs

Entering fun1()
abspath = /abc/chdir.py
file = chdir.py
__file__ = chdir.py
dname = /abc
CWD - fun1() = /abc
Entering fun2()
CWD - fun2() = /xyz/testdir
Sleeping for 5 secs
```

i.e. During the second (and subsequent iterations) the script should return to original directory.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want the same working directory in `function 1` on the second iteration as it was in the first iteration. So the `function 1`  will return always same working directory using the script directory.

```
import time
import sys, os
script = sys.argv[0]
ab_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
s_directory=os.path.dirname(ab_path)

def fun1():
    abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    print ('script path =================={}',s_directory)
    print('abspath = {}'.format(abspath))
    print('file = {}'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    print('__file__ = {}'.format(__file__))
    print('dname = {}'.format(s_directory))
    os.chdir(s_directory)
    print('CWD - fun1() = {}'.format(os.getcwd()))
    print('**************************************fun1*******************************')

def fun2():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    if cwd != '/home/test/testdir':
     os.chdir("/home/test/testdir")
     print('CWD - fun2() = {}'.format(os.getcwd()))
     print('**************************************fun2*******************************')

def main():
    while True:
     print('Entering fun1()')
     fun1()
     print('Entering fun2()')
     fun2()
     print('Sleeping for 5 secs')
     time.sleep(5)
     print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`__file__` is the name of the script file alone without the startup dir. And when you use `abspath` you get it via the current directory.
If you change the current directory, `abspath` will return something else. So if you want to capture the startup directory, just use `os.path.getcwd()` as you used in func2.

Comment: Even if you use ```os.path.getcwd()``` after changing the directory in ```fun2()```, it prints the changed directory name.